# How to define custom color ramps for specifically defined, continuous intervals in R (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, graphics

I'm trying to create a plot in which I can customize the color ramp to have exact colors at particular threshold values, and I want to define the color transition/ramp between thresholds.

For instance, suppose I want to plot prevalence of a disease across a map, and I want

- prev = 0 --> black
- 0 <= prev < 1  --> quick transition from black to purple, purple in between, and then a quick transition from purple to dark-blue.
- 1 <= prev < 10 --> quick transition from dark blue to blue , blue in between, and then a quick transition from blue to green.
- 10 <= prev < 50 --> quick transition from green to yellow, yellow to orange in between, and then a quick transition from orange to red.
- prev >= 50 --> transition from red to dark red.

My solutions have been to define a color rap of length 101, and defining each interval to approximate the desired color values.

See below for my approach.  Can anyone suggest a better way?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(terra) # map.pal
library(grid)
library(scales)
library(viridis) 
library(RColorBrewer)

ggplot(
  data = 
    tibble(
      x = seq(0,1, length.out = 500),
      y = 0
    ),
  mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color = x)
) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 150) +
  scale_color_gradientn(
    colours = 
      c(
        "black", "#22002A",                                   # 0 to 1
        colorRampPalette(map.pal("viridis")[c(1, 8)])(5),     # 1 to 6
        colorRampPalette(c(map.pal("viridis")[c(9, 18)]))(2), # 6 to 8
        colorRampPalette(c(map.pal("viridis")[c(19, 48)]))(2),# 8 to 10
        colorRampPalette(
          c(map.pal("viridis")[49], 
            map.pal("haxby")[37], 
            "darkorange", 
            "red"))(55),                                      # 10 to 50
        colorRampPalette(c("red", "darkred"))(32),            # 50 to 99
        rep("white", 1)                                       # 100
      ),
    limits = c(0,1),
    breaks = c(0.1,  0.5),
    labels = c(0.1,  0.5),
    name = "Prevalence"
  ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0.01) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0.1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0.5) +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  ylim(c(-0.012, 0.012))
```

As you can see below, I am close, but (1) not exact, and (2) the process is very tedious.

[image]

Please share alternate, more exact approaches if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making this more complex than it needs to be. You don't need a color ramp with `scale_gradientn` - it is already creating a color ramp. All you need to do is specify the colors and the values where you want them to change based on your specifications:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

cols <- c("black", "#22002A", "#443882", "#2F5B8E", 
  "#2D708E", "#3D8090", "#1F905B", "#E3E418", "darkorange2", "red", 
  "darkred", "white")

transitions <- c(0, 0.1, 0.9, 1.1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 49, 51, 99.9, 100)
```

The only complication is that you need to scale the transistions into the `c(0, 1)` range:

```r
scaled_transitions <- rescale(transitions, from = c(0, 100), to = c(0, 1))
```

Now you have a color scale that is mapped as desired into the 0-100 range by using the `scale_fill_gradientn` arguments `colors` and `values`

```r
ggplot(data.frame(x = seq(0, 100, length.out = 500)), aes(x, 0, fill = x)) +
  geom_raster(interpolate = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = cols, values = scaled_transitions) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(1, 10, 50), linewidth = 0.3)
```

[image]

You can tweak the values of the transitions in the above code if you want more or less abrupt changes between the colors.

We can see how this would look in a map-like set-up. We would expect a smoothly varying field to end up looking like a contour map:

```r
set.seed(1)
m <- MASS::kde2d(x = runif(5), runif(5), n = 500, lims = c(-.5, 1.5, -.5, 1.5))
df <- expand.grid(x = m$x, y = m$y)
df$z <- rescale(as.vector(m$z), from = range(m$z), to = c(0, 99))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = cols, values = scaled_transitions,
                       limits = c(0, 100)) +
  coord_equal(expand = FALSE) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much.  I couldn't find a similar answer online, so this is very helpful.